# CSS dilemma hiding children based on 2 conditions

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm having a parent with arbitrary amount of blocks inside, 2 in a row. The last one when it's odd is hidden so the there's no row with 1 element.

A new problem arose when I started to add .display-none classes to some of the elements, and in the case when it's 5 elements like on the picture, when I added hiding class to the 4th element we are left with 3 elements because the 5th one is still hidden according to the rule. Is it possible to hide the last child via CSS only when it's odd in the dom structure, as well as it's odd considering how many of the previous blocks were hidden via the hiding class?

Comment: As you've discovered, to use this method you'd have to remove the elements which are display: none. Is using JS OK?

Comment: @AHaworth im trying to figure out css only solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following selector `.box > *:nth-child(odd  of :not(.none)):last-child`. First select all the elements that are not having the class "none" then consider the odd elements from them and finally pick the last child.

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
.box * {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: red;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

.box > *:nth-child(odd  of :not(.none)):last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div class="none"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div class="none"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div class="none"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="none"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the solution thanks. didn't know about 'of' will research it now.

Comment: still using this. though i've noticed it doesn't work on safari desktop. not supported yet?

Answer (score 0):

You actually wrote the answer in the image you posted :)

```
   .box:nth-child(odd):last-child{
      display:none;
   }
```

Comment: yes this is the code to hide the last image if it's odd. (lets say we have 3 images so the 3d one is hidden). but now I hid the 2nd image with .hide class and we're left with only 1 image to display and in this case I want to display the last one

Answer (score -1):

Try using this: `.grid-cont:last-child:nth-child(odd) .grid-item:last-child {display: none;}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).